# Spritekit Subclassed node shows as nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, subclassing, skspritenode

Heyo folks, having a weird issue when trying to create a subclassed node in SpriteKit. I get no errors at compile, and app runs until I progress to where the node needs to be added as a child of the scene, then fails and says `reason: 'Attemped to add nil node to parent:` I'm not sure what I'm missing, any help is appreciated! Here's my header for the node:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface Ships : SKSpriteNode

-(Ships *)initWithImageNamed: (NSString *)imageName;

@end
```

And here's the implementation:

```
#import "Ships.h"

@implementation Ships

-(Ships *)initWithImageNamed: (NSString *)imageName
{
self = [Ships spriteNodeWithImageNamed:imageName];

// Adds more accurate physics body for ship collisions
CGFloat offsetX = (self.frame.size.width * 1.2) * self.anchorPoint.x;
CGFloat offsetY = (self.frame.size.height * 1.2) * self.anchorPoint.y;

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 8 - offsetX, 30 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 7 - offsetX, 22 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 50 - offsetX, 2 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 65 - offsetX, 7 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 70 - offsetX, 8 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 27 - offsetX, 31 - offsetY);

CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
self.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0f;
self.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
self.physicsBody.linearDamping = 1.0f;
self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;

// Keeps player ship on top of all other objects(unless other objects are assigned greater z position
self.zPosition = 100.0f;

return self;
}

@end
```

Then in my scene, I declare `playerNode` in `interface` with: `Ships *playerNode;` and here's the method that attempts to implement the node:

```
-(void) createPlayerNode
{
playerNode = [playerNode initWithImageNamed:@"Nova-L1"];
playerNode.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/5, self.frame.size.height/2);
playerNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategoryPlayer;
playerNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
playerNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategoryBottom | CollisionCategoryObject | CollisionCategoryScore | CollisionCategoryPup;

[self addChild:playerNode];
}
```

and I call `[self createPlayerNode];` elsewhere in the app, and as soon as I do...crash. Any help is greatly appreciated! Also, I'm running on my iPhone 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initializer for Ships is an instance method not a class method, so your alloc/init statement should be

```
playerNode = [[Ships alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"Nova-L1"]];
```

and in Ships.m, replace

```
self = [Ships spriteNodeWithImageNamed:imageName];
```

with this

```
self = [super initWithImageNamed:imageName];
```

Additionally, you should release the path after creating the physics body...

```
    ship.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];

    CGPathRelease(path);
```

Alternatively, you can declare a convenience method in Ships.m to alloc/init in a single step.

**EDIT:**

Declare class method in Ships.m

```
+ (Ships *)shipNodeWithImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName
{
    return [[Ships alloc] initWithImageNamed:imageName];
}
```

Add method prototype to Ships.h

```
+ (Ships *)shipNodeWithImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName;
```

and create a new ship node by

```
playerNode = [Ships shipNodeWithImageNamed:@"Nova-L1"];
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the info, and catching the path release thing. What would it look like to declare a convenience method in my ships implementation? Are we talking like a factory method? So I'd add something like 

    `+(id)ships {
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
    }`

Comment: Very cool. I tend to overcomplicate things in my head way too much. Thanks so much for the help!